# Make Dojo router respond to urls with no hastah

Tags: javascript, dojo

Is there a way to make Dojo router component respond to routes without the hashtag (#) ?

I want to make it respond to localhost/myapp/module, instead of localhost/myapp/#/module

Comment: did you mean /#module ?

Comment: I just want it to recognize changes in all url, withou using an # character

Comment: without # then you are talking about getting new page from the server each time url changes, is that what you want?  As far as I know, dojo router doesn't handle what you are asking, it's purpose is to prevent requesting page again from the server on hash change

Comment: You will need to extend `dojo/router` and `dojo/hash`, or implement your own routing, the [dojo versions does not support HTML5 navigation](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/hash/#caveats)